# Hola amigos, me pueden apoyar en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, objeto

Quiero obtener los valores de identificador y teléfono del siguiente objeto y poder almacenarlos en variables distintas en javascript.

[image: Imagen donde muestra en consola el objeto]

Comment: Pon en el título _cuál es el problema_, y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 2):

Con esto debería ser suficiente:

```
const identificador = [nombre_del_object]._customData.queueVariables.identificador
const telefono = [nombre_del_object]._customData.queueVariables.telefono
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], al margen de que la pregunta quedó cerrada tu aporte puede mejorar mucho si le explicas al OP que hace tu código